# Batch file to write incremental numbers

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I need a batch script to get the input from user and write it to second column in a text file. Below is the one I tried, but it just create the incremental sequence of numbers, but I cant place them in the right place.

```
set /p rows: Enter number of rows:

for /l %%g in (1,1,%rows%) do echo %%g>> myfile.txt
```

`myfile.txt` is a comma separated file having 10 columns.

I want the incremental row numbers to come in second column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `myfile.txt` file looks something like this

```
h,e,l,l,o,b,a,l,i,c
```

Then this

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p num=Enter number of rows:
set /a row=1
for /f "tokens=1-10 delims=," %%a in (myfile.txt) do (
echo %%a,!row!,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f,%%g,%%h,%%i,%%j >>new.txt
set /a row+=1
if !row! gtr !num! goto :BREAK
)
:BREAK
del myfile.txt /f /q
ren new.txt myfile.txt
```

Will output

```
h,1,e,l,l,o,b,a,l,i,c  
h,2,e,l,l,o,b,a,l,i,c
```

Comment: Bali C, i tried your code, this repeats the same number again.

Comment: @davidb Sorry, I realised that just after I posted and corrected it in my own script, without updating the answer, updated now!

Comment: Thanks Bali C, i have one more question, could you help me, example i have a text file and i have multiple delimeters in that text file, i need to find the string "line=" and add incremental numbers, like line=1, line=2, line=3.. is it possible?

Comment: You could search for the line and replace it with incrementing numbers like `set string=line=` then replace it with `set string=%string:line==line=!num!%`

Comment: No worries. I can't really without seeing exactly what your trying to do, my suggestion was only pseudo code, why don't you post another question with your exact requirements and then send me the link and I can have a look?